# Font awesome icon does not get bigger although fa-5 is set

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

My pen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/YPxBEJ

Why is the rss icon so small? It does not resize whatever fa-x I use?

```
<div class="container">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">

                          <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-icon">
                              <div class="container">
                                <div class="info-icons">
                                   <i class="fa fa-rss-square fa-5"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>  

                        </div>  
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
                          </div>  
                    </div>                        
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Didn't you mean to use the class `fa-5x`?

```
<i class="fa fa-rss-square fa-5x"></i>
```

Examples: https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/#larger

Comment: argh..... yes i have not seen the x this damn crap vga monitor with analog cable. All day and my eyes get blurry. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Also important to know that you can achieve larger icons by setting a higher font size of that element/it's parent.

Font-awesome icons are just fonts, meaning they are vectors and scale up beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this also:**

```
<i class="fa fa-home" style="font-size:20px;"></i>
```

`font-size` will also **increase/decrease** the size of icon.